# CronD ignoring command and running hourly

Tags: centos, cron

Having a problem with Cron on Centos7 it appears to be running my command

```
5 * * * * root curl http://www.(removed)/Ebay/GetOrders.php
```

every hour instead of the 5 minutes i set some of the log:

```
Jan 12 14:05:01 (removed)-http CROND[25392]: (root) CMD (curl http://www.   (removed)(removed)/Ebay/GetOrders.php)
Jan 12 14:05:01 (removed)-http CROND[25393]: (root) CMD (root curl http://www.(removed)(removed)/Ebay/GetOrders.php)
Jan 12 15:01:01 (removed)-http CROND[12453]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
Jan 12 15:01:01 (removed)-http run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[12453]: starting 0anacron
Jan 12 15:01:01 (removed)-http run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[12462]: finished 0anacron
Jan 12 15:01:01 (removed)-http run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[12453]: starting 0yum-hourly.cron
Jan 12 15:01:01 (removed)-http run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[12468]: finished 0yum-hourly.cron
Jan 12 15:05:01 (removed)-http CROND[13880]: (root) CMD (curl http://www.(removed)(removed)/Ebay/GetOrders.php)
Jan 12 15:05:01 (removed)-http CROND[13881]: (root) CMD (root curl http://www.(removed)(removed)/Ebay/GetOrders.php)
Jan 12 15:26:25 (removed)-http crontab[21340]: (root) LIST (root)
Jan 12 15:39:08 (removed)-http crontab[25757]: (root) LIST (root)
Jan 12 15:39:26 (removed)-http crond[3275]: (CRON) INFO (Shutting down)
Jan 12 15:39:26 (removed)-http crond[25906]: (CRON) INFO (RANDOM_DELAY will be scaled with factor 20% if used.)
Jan 12 15:39:26 (removed)-http crond[25906]: (CRON) INFO (running with inotify support)
Jan 12 15:39:26 (removed)-http crond[25906]: (CRON) INFO (@reboot jobs will be run at computer's startup.)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
5 * * * * root curl http://www.(removed)/Ebay/GetOrders.php
```

You configured it to run every hour, at five minutes after the hour.

What you want is:

```
*/5 * * * * root curl http://www.(removed)/Ebay/GetOrders.php
```